# Show Text Selection Contextual Action Bar (CAB) when selecting text using keyboard

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is there a way to show the Text Selection Contextual Action Bar (CAB) when users select text using the keyboard (using shift). Currently it only shows when selecting text using the touch screen. I can easily detect when text has been selected but have no idea on how to show the menu programatically.